# Matlab R2016a tab completion without hitting tab on ubuntu

Tags: linux, matlab, autocomplete

Is there any way, in matlab R2016a for Linux to use tab-completion without hitting the tab key

I recently switched from windows, where the autocompletion would pop up automaticly, but on linux it looks like i have to press tab for this to happen, wich makes it a lot slower (one more keystroke for every word)

There is one similiar question number 26249936, but it's a full year old, so something new might have happened

Thanks for the help

Comment: No nothing new has happened.

Comment: Actually `Tab` is is the most used key (and my favorite) for linux (terminal) users. It is a good practice to learn 10-finger-typing.

Comment: NKN I agree that the Tab key is good, but why do i have to tab it when the autocompletion could just pop up automaticly, i know how to use a keyboard, but I just dont see a reason to add a keystroke to my typing (on windows i would just type untill it recognized the variable i wanted and then tab enter)